# Building up a (small) Crowd-testing community

Tags: manual-testing

I am planning to build a small community of testers for my mobile application, a sort of crowd-testing group for exploratory/regression testing.
Does anyone have any suggestion on how to find people who would be available to test my latest release on a regular basis? since it's a health/fitness app, testers should be active (walk/run/work-outs ...).
Also, what is the "standard" for rewarding the testers? is it per bug found? is it flat fee?

Comment: There are no 'standards' like this on the internet, especially on a global scale.  You have to try and do what works for you, your app, your audience, your budget, your product, etc.  One thing to think about is what would (from the testers point of view) make this a 'community', not just a bunch of individual testers.  You might like to have a community but why would they?

Comment: A bug found for a solo developer 'joe' might have a $10 reward.  For google it might be $100,000

Comment: Generally once you find what works for you today, you'll need to change it "tomorrow" if your need continues. ("tomorrow" might be next month, years, etc).

Answer (score 1):

### Friends and Family

- Ask your family
- Ask your family members to each ask a friend
- Ask your personal friends
- Ask your personal friends to ask a  friend
- Ask your work friends for a favor

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments. While everyone can test by using an app, not everyone can see whether it's a bug or misuse of the software or is comfortable writing a ticket with all the information needed to reproduce the issue. That's why for instance I cannot ask my parents to help or some of my friends, or most of my neighbors.

Comment: Whoa, write a ticket?!  That's NOT what I expect a family member to do.  That's a part that YOU would have to take on.  Asking neighbors and friends is definitely hard.  The only thing I know that is harder is asking strangers to do it for free.

Comment: To be clear, this won't work for everyone, but it is posted as an answer as it will probably be a good approach for some in this situation.  Real world users can determine if they think a bug is a bug.  Domain knowledge might be a barrier though.

Comment: Not really sure how I feel about this - I wouldn't trust someone that loves me to give me honest feedback on a project!

Answer (score 0):

I'm highly torn whether or not this question is on topic or not. But the community doesn't seem to think so, so I'm not throwing my hammer at it, and I thought I'd throw an answer on it too.

The best crowd to test your app are the people who love your app. You could get people who love you, but they might be more interested in how you feel about what they say than what they actually say. It's hard to get honest feedback from them.

You could also get people who love testing. For iOS apps, there's https://www.reddit.com/r/TestFlight/ and for Android apps, there's https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidAppTesters/ - I'm sure there are others if you root around enough. And you may have success with this, but the people who are looking to test this particular app are unlikely to be familiar with your product domain.

But what about the people who actually use your app? They might not know testing, but they will know when things don't work the way they're supposed to. And I would never suggest to abandon professional testers entirely, especially if this is a for-profit enterprise. But you can easily reward people who test with a variety of different things.

First, early access and feedback means the things they want are more likely to get attention, which might be very valuable for them or their company. Such mutually beneficial relationships are wonderful (and a primary driver of FOSS applications, in my experience.)

Second, it's amazing what users will do for a badge of recognition. Stack Exchange literally wouldn't exist without it.

And finally, some people just feel good helping out a small business/operation. Everyone loves an underdog. I remember when I was a teenager playing video games there were some people who helped me gather all my materials for a huge project. At the time I kind of thought they were suckers for all the essentially free work they did. As I got older, I realized they were just having a good time and it gave them all a reason to hang out together.